# How to set up a relationship between two tables that are not directly dependent on each other with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have defined this models with Sequelize.js v3:

`Model1: cities`

Model2: districts
this.belongsTo(models.cities, {as: "city", foreignKey: 'city_id'});

Model3: streets
this.belongsTo(models.districts, {as: "district", foreignKey: 'district_id'});

Model4: houses
this.belongsTo(models.streets, {as: "street", foreignKey: 'street_id'});

Is there a way to set a relation between the models "cities" and "houses", so that chosen a city only the houses of that city are selected?
Or do I have to add the "city_id" column in the tables "districts" and "streets"?

I ask this because in the app I have to implement a page with only two comboboxes: city and houses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to go all the way dowm from `cities` to `houses`. And for that you actually need to make the association from top to bottom, right now you have it the other way arround. Let me explain.

With your actual associations your models calls each other on this way:

`houses -> streets -> districts -> cities`

Because `houses` depends from `streets` and so on. What we need is all to go to the other.

`cities -> districts -> streets -> houses`

```
Model1: cities
this.hasMany(models.districts, {as: "districts", foreignKey: 'city_id'});
```

And do the same for `districts` and `streets`.

Now for what you want we can do the following query.

```
cities.findAll({
  include: [{ 
    model: model.districts, 
    as: 'districts', 
    include: [{
      model: model.streets, 
      as: 'streets',
      include: [{
        model: model.houses, 
        as: 'houses',
        where: {} //your condition here
      }]
    }]
  }]
});
```

Now, the other way could be as you mention, that put an association directly from cities to houses, but that really depends on your schema and business model.